# Directly edit files of an FTP server using Atom

Tags: ftp, atom-editor

I have tried time and time again to get `remote-edit` working within atom. I have added my known working FTP server, click on the Browse Hosts button, and attempt to connect. I am 100% sure the username and password are correct. I don't know what kind of data to provide, other than it worked once, but has never worked again.

Answer (score 2):

From a look at the source, `remote-edit` prints all errors to the console. To open the console, open the *View* menu, then browse to *Developer* and click *Toggle Developer Tools*. Or use the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (it's probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> on Windows.) This should help finding the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am seeing no errors in the console. Nor anything else

Comment: Looks like I solved it, but I think something might still be up.